# Wechat H5 payment does not work

Tags: php, payment-gateway, wechat

I have successfully integrated qr code wechat payment.
It is pretty much pointless for mobile website. Client wants something more usable.
After some research I have found that H5 payment should do.
The thing is I am getting error and can't find anything on the web regarding the issue. The support is probably the worst I have ever dealt with. They tried to point to wrong config being used but when got full payloads, request and responses haven't come back with anything useful.

endpoint:
https://api.mch.weixin.qq.com/pay/unifiedorder

payload:

```
<xml>
  <appid><![CDATA[*appid*]]></appid>
  <mch_id>*merchantId*</mch_id>
  <body><![CDATA[Tickets]]></body>
  <detail><![CDATA[{"goods_detail":[[{"goods_id":"3_81","goods_name":"Wicked - 7 June 2018 07:30pm - STALLS K36","quantity":1,"price":1}]]}]]></detail>
  <out_trade_no>*11111*</out_trade_no>
  <fee_type><![CDATA[CNY]]></fee_type>
  <total_fee>1</total_fee>
  <spbill_create_ip><![CDATA[192.168.22.1]]></spbill_create_ip>
  <time_expire>20180602063844</time_expire>
  <notify_url><![CDATA[https://xyz2.local/wechat/confirmation/dfsdfs/erefdav]]></notify_url>
  <trade_type><![CDATA[MWEB]]></trade_type>
  <nonce_str><![CDATA[*nonce*]]></nonce_str>
  <sign><![CDATA[*sign*]]></sign>
</xml>
```

response:

```
<xml>
   <return_code><![CDATA[FAIL]]></return_code>
   <return_msg><![CDATA[商户号该产品权限预开通中，请等待产品开通后重试]]></return_msg>
</xml>
```

For wechat integration I am using this library: [omnipay-wechat](https://github.com/lokielse/omnipay-wechatpay)
All the data between ** is correctly populated.
Google translation doesn't make much sense to me. 
Tried to google for the error in Chinese but haven't found anything helpful.

Wasted already a lot of time.. Hope there is somebody witch wechat payment expierience that can point me to the right direction.

Comment: Please tell me how you get APPID and APIKEY (for generating sign)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The H5 payment is NOT opened by default. You have to request the approval.

Comment: Yes. It was misconfigured. Wechat support was not able to point me to the right direction.
It's worth to mention that the payment will work only with the configured urls and https/http as well as www/no www are important. Couldn't find the way to test it on local env as domain need to be approved so tunnelling won't work. Working on production though
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The error means the account linked to the given merchant id does not have the privileges yet for the request, you have to wait until the account get the approval and then try again.